# How to move a document from a pre-production to production instance in Kentico 7

Tags: kentico

We recently migrated a bunch of document updates up from a pre-production server to our production server.  We'd attempted to use content staging, which had worked mostly OK in the past, but this time it failed with a lot of parent records not found errors.  Our outsourced developer used the Documents tab of the Staging module to sync subtrees across.  However a few files got missed, or didn't work correctly the first time.  So I'm trying to move them now, and I'm running into a problem.

After expanding the content tree and clicking on the document in the Documents tab, and selecting the correct target server (we've got bi-directional staging set up), we're getting an error:  Dependent task 'Move document See Things Differently' failed:Synchronization server error: Exception occurred: SyncHelper.ServerError: Document node not found, please synchronize the document node first.

Looking at the tasks listed, I don't even see a Move document task anywhere queued up for the target server.

Is there any way I can move this document up to our production instance?  I've looked at the site export as an alternative, but it doesn't look like I can export just this one page.  Am I going to have to recreate the page on Production instead?

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to attempt this sync is to clear out all the staging tasks and do a full sync from the root of the website.  Most likely what happened to some of the documents which are stating "moved..." is the pages were reordered.  Which means every document below that document's parent will be updated on that level.  So simply moving or reordering one document out of 10, will trigger 10 staging tasks.  If you don't sync those to the production site, the order will be off according to the staging site.

Comment: Agree with Brenden, but want to add if you have many nodes in tree it might be better to sync one branch at the moment and repeat for all instead on running full sync.

Comment: That's what our outsourced developer did with this entire subtree a couple weekends ago.  It took multiple passes, starting with deleting the entire section from the production instance, then using the Staging module to sync first the top level document, then each sub-level page, and so on.

Comment: So @MattNewby did that approach not work or what was the issue with that?  And yes, do as Roman mentions if it is a large site with lots of nested nodes.

Comment: Re-syncing the entire subtree isn't an option at this point. The documents exist on our Acceptance server (business customers validate major projects here), but not on our Authoring server (intended for creating content, now a pre-release staging server for various reasons) and need to get to Prod. We create page content on Prod, which has been updated since this section got migrated a couple weekends ago. Apparently some pages didn't make it to Authoring, which was the source for the deployment, and those are the ones I need to move up from Acceptance through Authoring to Prod.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a problems similar to this before.

This typically works:

1. Create a copy of the document, put it in the same location in the
   content tree.
2. Delete the original document.
3. Make any changes to the new document name, URL, aliases, etc (remove the '1' for example)
4. Then push that new document with Kentico Staging.

Its a bit of a hack but sometimes necessary.

Comment: Done this approach many times @nbushnell and it seems to work most every time but as you say somewhat of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Brenden is right on target about clearing the staging tasks listed under "All tasks" before you try syncing again. We've run into these errors on our sites when we've tried pushing a large number of docs from staging to production. What worked for us was deleting all pending and failed "Pages" tasks, then under the content tree in "Pages," navigating to the first child level and syncing "Current page" all the way to the closest parent directory, and then syncing "Current subtree."

For instance, if the problem doc is in, say, the "18" dir, select Articles and sync current page, then 2016, then 01, and for 18 sync current subtree.

[content tree syncing screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HjnQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Kentico in-built Staging module and use that to first move objects and then the pages.

I have never faced any problem moving a large number of nodes(around 8000). That's the best possible approach.

In case your website a large no of custom table items let's say 50K, then I would do an export/import of the table. Synching so many entries usually has given Connection Time Out error before.

Thanks,
Chetan